# The "A theory of moderation" blog post is outdated

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, user-interface

In the Review queues (https://stackoverflow.com/review) page, I noticed the following

[image: 1]

The link points to https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/.

I read the article, but I quickly noticed that it is kinda outdated, as it contains a much older GUI (the article is from 2009) and outdated features, like the flag menu.

Do you also think this link should point somewhere else or there is a reason for this?

Comment: It's a blog post (the date is in the URL) so it'd be weird to retrospectively edit it to be up to date. Perhaps the link could point to something (new?) in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq)?

Comment: Yeah, this seems more logical